# Terraform Modules - Recognizing child module variables from root

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Versioning:

```
Terraform v0.15.0
on linux_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.37.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random v3.1.0
```

I have the following folder structure:

```
terraform/
├── main.tf
└── terraform.tfvars
├── core
│   ├── main.tf
│   └── variables.tf
```

The files of concern here are:

```
terraform/main.tf
terraform/terraform.tfvars
core/main.tf
core/variables.tf
```

The high-level overview is I'm trying to use TF to create a VPC in AWS, using the terraform-aws-vpc module, so my root module is calling the core module which calls the terraform-provided vpc module to build. The reason it's a child calling a child is that once I get this vpc step working, the "core" module is going to be responsible for building other infrastructure assets in the account. The idea is to have the root module call a child module for each important piece of the AWS Account assets.

The problem I'm running into here is one of variables.

In `core/`, I have the following variables defined in `core/variables.tf`:

```
variable "vpc_facts" {
    type = map
}
```

That variable is referenced for information for the vpc module in `core/main.tf`:

```
module "vpc" {
    source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"

    name = var.vpc_facts.name
    cidr = var.vpc_facts.cidr
}
```

I define these values, which I hope will be passed into the module, in `terraform/terraform.tfvars`:

```
vpc_facts = {
    name = "demo-vpc"
    cidr = "192.168.0.0/16" 
}
```

I then call the core module from `terraform/main.tf`

```
module "core" {
    source = "./core/"
}
```

I am trying to call `terraform plan` from my root folder of `terraform/` - I have included the `core` as a module within `terraform/main.tf`

My thought process here is `terraform/main.tf -> gathers terraform/terraform.tfvars -> core module -> uses terraform/terraform.tfvars as input variables for vpc module`

However, that doesn't seem to be happening. I keep getting this error when running `terraform plan` from the root module folder:

```
Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...
╷
│ Warning: Value for undeclared variable
│ 
│ The root module does not declare a variable named "vpc_facts" but a value was found in file "terraform.tfvars". If you meant to use
│ this value, add a "variable" block to the configuration.
│ 
│ To silence these warnings, use TF_VAR_... environment variables to provide certain "global" settings to all configurations in your
│ organization. To reduce the verbosity of these warnings, use the -compact-warnings option.
╵
╷
│ Error: Missing required argument
│ 
│   on main.tf line 57, in module "core":
│   57: module "core" {
│ 
│ The argument "vpc_facts" is required, but no definition was found.
```

I would guess this should already be defined since I'm defining it in both tfvars and core/variables, but when I actually try to define it in the root main.tf:

```
module "core" {
    source = "./core/"
    
    vpc_facts = var.vpc_facts
}
```

I get a different error:

```
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared input variable
│ 
│   on main.tf line 60, in module "core":
│   60:     vpc_facts = var.vpc_facts
│ 
│ An input variable with the name "vpc_facts" has not been declared. This variable can be declared with a variable "vpc_facts" {}
│ block.
```

but **it is** declared, in `core/variables.tf` and valued in `terraform/terraform.tfvars`

What am I missing here? Does this mean I need to repeatedly define variables in both child modules and the root module? I would think that if a root module is calling a child module, it's a flat structure in terms of variables, and that child module can see child/variables.tf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this mean I need to repeatedly define variables in both child modules and the root module?

Yes, exactly what it means. All modules are self-contained, and a child module **does not inherit variables** from the parent. You have to explicitly define the variables in the module, and then set them in the parent module when you create the module.